# Print 7x6 two-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range, type-2-dimension

I need to print a two-dimensional list for a connect four game with 7 columns and 6 rows. Here is my code but it only prints a 6x6 table. The global constants from the connectfour module are: BOARD_ROWS = 6 and BOARD_COLUMNS = 7

```
    def print_board(game_state: list)-> None:
        for i in range(connectfour.BOARD_ROWS):
            for j in range(connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS):
                if j != connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS -1:
                    if game_state[j][i] == connectfour.NONE:
                        print('.', end=' ')
                    elif game_state[j][i] == connectfour.RED:
                        print('R', end=' ')
                    elif game_state[j][i] == connectfour.YELLOW:
                        print('Y', end=' ')
                else:
                    print('\n',end='')
```

This is the output I get:

```
    . . . . . . 
    . . . . . . 
    Y . . . . . 
    R . . . . . 
    R . . . . . 
    R R R Y Y Y
```

As you can see there are only 6 columns. However I know the 7th one is there because in this particular output the "Y" player won after dropping a piece in the 7th column. I just don't understand why it doesn't print the 7th column. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you should take a look at the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module. You can draw over parts of the screen without having to re-print the board every time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for this program I am specifically asked to update and print the board after every move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if j != connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS -1:` means you are specifically excluding the last column.  Remove that `if` construction and undent the following `if`s and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you! that worked. One of my lab tutors told me to put that line but I didn't fully understood what it did, I tried taking out the -1 but it would just print one big line. This worked though thanks. I want to make the board look cleaner though by numbering the columns on top, so like:

Comment: Sorry I couldn't type it, but basically a row at the top of the board with "1 2 3 4 5 6 7". Any help on how to do that?

Comment: As the first line of your ``print_board`` function, do this: ``print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7")``

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, feel free to select it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help didn't realize it was that simple.